Appendix: Secondary data
Using secondary data for my research. I will be using the responses of an external survey to run an analysis. Should I be adding the survey as an Appendix?

Is this for a thesis or a paper? Because if it is the latter, copyright issues may arise.

Where did you get the secondary data? Did you need to sign a contract to access them?

What do you mean when you say "secondary data"?

This is a question for your advisor, but you should probably include it, provided you can get permission from its author(s). Failing that, you can, of course, refer to it and cite it so that public information is available for those who need to follow up.
Depending on where you find it, there can be copyright issues to settle with the publisher.
If the survey was created by yourself, there are fewer issues unless it has been published and you don't hold copyright.
Generally include things that are necessary to evaluate your work, or, when necessary, references to them. And cite others always.
